# How to load specific Firefox profile into selenium (Macos M1)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to load a specific profile into selenium, but it always opens with the default profile. Here is my code:

```
profile_path = '/Users/mymachine/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/specificprofile.default'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
service = FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
```

I also tried with direct indication of the gecko driver, but it doesn't work also.

```
service = webdriver.FirefoxService(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
```

When I log the output, I obtain this:

```
1695479350799   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: MOZ_CRASHREPORTER="1" MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_NO_REPORT="1" MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN="1" MOZ_NO_REMOTE="1" "/App ... s" "localhost" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/rust_mozprofileecFA3Z"
console.warn: services.settings: Ignoring preference override of remote settings server
console.warn: services.settings: Allow by setting MOZ_REMOTE_SETTINGS_DEVTOOLS=1 in the environment
1695479351216   Marionette      INFO    Marionette enabled
console.error: "Warning: unrecognized command line flag" "-remote-allow-hosts"
1695479351323   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 60997
Read port: 60997
WebDriver BiDi listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60987
1695479351366   RemoteAgent     WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
UNSUPPORTED (log once): POSSIBLE ISSUE: unit 1 GLD_TEXTURE_INDEX_2D is unloadable and bound to sampler type (Float) - using zero texture because texture unloadable
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60987/devtools/browser/2bbd8a80-f4ee-46a3-875d-7be3c1b2d504
console.warn: services.settings: Ignoring preference override of remote settings server
console.warn: services.settings: Allow by setting MOZ_REMOTE_SETTINGS_DEVTOOLS=1 in the environment
console.error: (new TypeError("lazy.AsyncShutdown.profileBeforeChange is undefined", "resource://services-settings/Database.sys.mjs", 593))
```

where `"-profile" "/var/folders/0k/hz9yngm56nz1htdc3c3t3d0c0000gn/T/rust_mozprofileecFA3Z"`calls my attention, as indicates that it is creating a temporary profile.

I'm in MacOS Darwin M1, with selenium 4.12.0, webdriver-manager 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was this. Under selenium 4.18.1.

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("-profile")
options.add_argument(profile_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and after some research the following code worked for me:

```
service = Service()
options = Options()
profile_path = profile_path = '/Users/mymachine/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/specificprofile.default'
options.profile = FirefoxProfile(profile_path)

driver= webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
```

The key thing to do was to specify the root path for the profile instead of the local path, which solved the problem. Accordingly, change profile_path from

```
profile_path = '/Users/mymachine/AppData/Local/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/specificprofile.default'
```

to

```
profile_path = '/Users/mymachine/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/specificprofile.default'
```

Note: I'm using Selenium 4.14 on Windows.

Comment: Thanks but it's not applicable to Macos.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below snippet to do what you require:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import service

service_args=[]
# Important to have each instruction/value pair split into their own items
service_args.append("--profile")
service_args.append("/path/to/profile")
service = service.Service(service_args=service_args)
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
```

Not what you need, but should you wish for Firefox to use a different path to create temporary profiles, replace `"--profile"` with `"--profile-root"`.

Documentation for [`--profile-root`](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Flags.html) and [`--profile`](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Profiles.html). The Marionette bug mentioned has now been fixed.

Comment: Can't make it work. I'm getting `selenium.webdriver.common.service:Started executable: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver in a child process with pid: 75391 using 0 to output None
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver: error: unexpected argument --profile found

  tip: a similar argument exists: --profile-root`

Comment: The --profile argument is valid, see the docs I referenced. Which geckodriver version are you using? Selenium should download the latest for you if you don't specify a binary path to it. Did you try the other answer proposed by rsp96? That is a valid solution for MacOS.

Comment: I left below what worked for me.