# Load firefox default profile in selenium 4.18.1 python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to load My default profile of firefox but cant load it I have tried all kinds of approach but nothing is working please help.

The approaches i have tried please anyone help with this

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_profile('/path/to/default/profile')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.profile = '/path/to/default/profile'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import os


ffOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

ffOptions.add_argument("-profile")
ffOptions.add_argument(f"{os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')}\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\a9uwbprg.default-release-1708619541786")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=ffOptions)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import os


ffOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

ffOptions.profile= webdriver.FirefoxProfile(f"{os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')}\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\a9uwbprg.default-release-1708619541786")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=ffOptions)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

pf = f"{os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')}\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\a9uwbprg.default-release-1708619541786"
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', pf)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https:google.com")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there, but you are using `LOCALAPPDATA` not `APPDATA`.

Thus the profile path string should be:

```
f"{os.getenv('APPDATA')}\\Roaming"
+ "\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\a9uwbprg.default-release-1708619541786"
```

In summary of your snippets:

1. There is no `Options().set_profile` as far as I am aware.
2. Should work if the correct path is used.
3. Should also work if the correct path is used.
4. Same as 2, 3, and 4.
5. Not sure if this is still supported. The other methods are more direct.

Bonus [one additional way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78046663/3822101) to load a profile.

Comment: thank u bro do you how to select the default profile if multiple profile are there?? In my profiles directory there are three profiles, and all have the word default in them.

Comment: If you type `about:profiles` in Firefox, it will bring up the Profile Manager. Not sure how you do this if needed programmatically.

Comment: It seems the default profile is saved in the `...\Firefox\profiles.ini` file. Look for the `Path=` above `Default=1`